# Mac OS X Office 2004 file doesn't open when I double-click

Tags: macos, office-for-mac

When I download an Office file and double click it from the Downloads window or from [Finder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_%28software%29), the associated program will open, but the file won't. It worked before I upgraded from [Tiger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#Version_10.4:_.22Tiger.22) to [Snow Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#Version_10.6:_.22Snow_Leopard.22). How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update Office as well as Mac OS X ?

Some earlier version were not compatible with Snow Leopard (even if the last one isn't 100% reliable).

Latest version available is [11.5.7](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads.mspx?pid=Mactopia_Office2004&fid=7C985595-00C5-44B8-81C3-59D9967220F8#viewer).

Make sure you also have [Rosetta](http://www.apple.com/rosetta/) installed (it comes on Snow Leopard DVD).

But even with all this, Office 2004 code is PPC only and isn't supported anymore …

Comment: Yeah, it's updated to the latest version.